# Why is this relation an equivalence relation on $G\setminus \{e\}$ if and only if $o(g)$ is prime for each $g \in G\setminus \{e\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $G\setminus \{e\}$ if and only if $o(g)$ is prime for each $g \in G\setminus \{e\}$,
>
> where $\sim$ is defined on $G\setminus \{e\}$ by $g \sim h$ if and only if $g^k = h$ for some $k \geq 1$,
>
> $g, h \in G\setminus \{e\}$, $e$ is the identity element of $G$, and $o(g)$ is the order of $g$.

It's pretty easy to prove reflexivity and transitivity, but I can't seem to be able to put a finger on symmetricity. That's also where the prime number condition seems to come in.

Hope it's an interesting problem. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $g^k = h$, then $h$ is in the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$. If the order of $g$ is prime, then...? Otherwise...?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ahh I kind of get this line of thinking, but can't seem to take it far enough. If the order of g is not prime, then there must exist a unique subgroup of the cyclic subgroup generated by g, and something about it makes it impossible for symmetricity? Not exactly sure though...

Comment: Focus on one direction first. If the order of $g$ is prime, then the subgroup generated by $g$ has prime order, and that means...?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Then by Fermat's Little Theorem, you can get to the first member of that subgroup, from any starting position, by taking it to the a^(p-1)th power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** The relation is symmetric if and only if 
$$g\sim h \Longleftrightarrow h\sim g$$
if and only if
$$h\in \langle g\rangle \Longleftrightarrow g\in\langle h\rangle$$
if and only if
$$\langle h\rangle\subseteq \langle g\rangle \Longleftrightarrow \langle g\rangle\subseteq \langle h\rangle$$
if and only if
$$\langle h\rangle \subseteq \langle g\rangle \Longleftrightarrow \langle h\rangle = \langle g\rangle$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I was able to do the other side but I can't figure why symmetry implies that the order must be prime?

Comment: @Human: If the order is not prime, can you have $\langle h\rangle\subseteq \langle g\rangle$ **without** $\langle h\rangle = \langle g \rangle$?

Comment: Yeah cuz Lagrange's theorem right?

Comment: @Human No, Lagrange tells you subgroups have certain divisibility conditions. It does not tell you that certain divisibility conditions imply the existence of subgroups.

Comment: Then I can construct a specific counterexample but don't know about the general case

Comment: @Human: It's about properties of cyclic groups, not about Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: Or perhaps since Lagrange's theorem implies that every order divides the group cardinality then as the group is finite all the orders are finite and perhaps if the order is not prime and  not all the group elements necessarily generate the group so there must be a subgroup?

Comment: @Human. For the second time, no. Lagrange's Theorem says that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $G$ is finite, then $|H|$ divides $|G|$. What you need here is that if the **cyclic** group $\langle g\rangle$ does not have prime order, then it has a proper nontrivial cyclic subgroup. So this is about **cyclic** groups, not about Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: Thanks!I got it I tried an example like C4 and clearly <g^2> is a proper subgroup then I saw that in general any d|k for k non prime corresponds to a non trivial subgroup.